# nodemon keeps crashing waiting for file changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, nodemon

Cloned a project that I completed 2 months ago, and unfortunately, nodemon won't run. I've tried using task manager on windows to close npm and run it again and I still keep getting the same error. I'm also using monogodb as my database as well if that helps.

I've left a link here to my repository if anybody can help?

https://github.com/Tashfinz/ExpressNodeBlog

**Error:**

> ```
> $ nodemon server
> [nodemon] 2.0.4
> [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
> [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
> [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
> [nodemon] starting `node server global.js`
> C:\Users\tashf\Documents\Projects\ExpressNodeBlog\global.js:17
> console.log(document.querySelector);
>            ^
>
> ReferenceError: document is not defined
>    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tashf\Documents\Projects\ExpressNodeBlog\global.js:17:13)
>    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
>    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
>    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
>    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
>    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
>    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to kill the node server process

in Windows, go to task manager and end the process.

Now run the node server: example- “nodemon server.js”

in most cases, it should work else try “npm install” to re-install the packages then try “nodemon server.js”.

I hope this would help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still receiving the same issue. Just to clarify the process to end with task manager is "Node.js: Server-side Javascript" because I've ended the task via task manager and ran nodemon and still the same exact issue. And I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

uninstall and install again works for me

```
npm un nodemon
npm i nodemon
```

Comment: tried uninstalling nodemon and reinstalling I've even installed it globally and still the same issue persists.

Comment: keep in mind that if you are using some particular way to run **npm start** (check the script in package.json) you have to set the same way to run nodemon

Comment: {
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "global.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.20",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
I realised the script is trying to use npm runs serve for a server.js file which I removed for use with app.js, so I could use ejs instead.  I use nodemon instead of npm to run the server.

Comment: does this run on your machine? I left the repository as a link in the original post

Answer (score 0):

**Reasons & Solutions:**

***First:***

Maybe your PC running several processes in the Background. So you need to stop all the node process that are running.

***Quick trick:***

Kill them all by running this on terminal :

```
pkill -f node
```

or to kill a particular port instead of all

```
sudo lsof -i :3000//replace 3000 with your port number

sudo kill -9 31363// replace 31363 with your PID
```

and then restart nodemon.

***Second:***

Server.js and package.json are not in the same folder.

*check package.json File.*

And In MAIN YourNode.js file and SCRIPT start: nodemon YourNode.js has SAME NAME.